# Facebook: Post automatically to group's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there are current method that allows to post on the facebook wall of your own group by a script without being a company? I have seen a lot of stackoverflow posts here but none works anymore because acquiring a token for the **facebook-graph-api** to post by a script is not possible for personal use (**Facebook**: "We determined that your app's use case for this permission is invalid, or it's not needed to support its core functionality."). It seems as Facebook only allows apps that are used by users, however I need to create an app that posts regularly updates into the group by a script. I have also tried to use a selenium script but got blocked by Facebook.

There are wordpress plugins that allows to post on Facebook automatically. Why does Facebook allows this but not the integration of my own database?